# Ctypes Text Input Box Help Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

How to make a popup window with an text input box in Ctypes using python 3 or using MessageBoxW,if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works!

```
import ctypes
MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
MessageBox(None, 'Hello', 'Window title', 0)
```

Comment: I have to point out that they requested a "text input box", which MessageBox is not.

Comment: "or using MessageBoxW"